# Why is Time not setting when inserting new task using Task Service?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-tasks

I am trying to insert new task with due date and time in Google Tasks using Tasks Service. The issue i am facing is that date is setting correctly while time is not setting. The code is given below:

I had tried all the solutions given on stackoverflow and other platform, none of them worked.

```
      var task = Tasks.newTask().setTitle(data[i]);
      task.setDue("2019-6-25T10:10:10.000Z");
      Tasks.Tasks.insert(task, taskList.id);
```

I expect both the date and time to be set but only date is setting.

Comment: You can vote on Google's public issue tracker to make this data accessible via the API. The issue is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128979662. You can vote on the issue if you are affected by it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official document says as follows.

> Due date of the task (as a RFC 3339 timestamp). Optional. The due date only records date information; the time portion of the timestamp is discarded when setting the due date. It isn't possible to read or write the time that a task is due via the API.

Unfortunately, in the current stage, by above specification, even if `2019-6-25T10:10:10.000Z` is used for `due`, it becomes `2019-06-25T00:00:00.000Z`. So it seems that in order to modify the time, it is required to manually modify it.

#### Reference:

- [Resource representations of Tasks](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks#resource)